# BLOB couldn't be deserialized: invalid type code after trying to edit a BLOB in MySQL

Tags: mysql, report, quartz-scheduler

Here is the scenario: I am trying manually insert rows in to some QUARTZ Scheduler tables in order to run a report. In some of those tables, there is a BLOB field for the job data. With my latest attempt, I am currently taking an existing BLOB, edit it using CONVERT() and REPLACE(), and then insert this result in to another row. Here's an example:

```
SET @blob1 = (SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(params USING latin1),'userA',username),'DAR1488391575227',CONCAT('DAR - ',username)),'Report Test 3',CONCAT('Report - ',username)),'03/01/17 01:08:00 PM',CONCAT(DATE(DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)),' 06:00:00')) FROM qrtz_custom_fired_triggers WHERE id = 12933);

INSERT INTO qrtz_custom_fired_triggers VALUES (CONCAT('Report - ',username),CONCAT(DATE(DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)),' 06:00:00'),NULL,'Created',@jobid,now(),NULL,@blob1,NULL,NULL,NULL,'-1',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,'GROUP_REPORTING',66,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

I am able to successfully create the trigger, however, errors like this occur when the job tries to run at it's scheduled time:

```
Error retrieving job, setting trigger state to ERROR. org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve job because the BLOB couldn't be deserialized: invalid type code: 4F [See nested exception: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 4F]
```

Am I going about this the wrong way? Any and all help is appreciated. I'll be sure to provide more information if necessary!

Comment: What is the value of blob1 and how does it compare to blobs created by the Quartz API?

Comment: It's the same (apparently/visually) as the blob created by Quartz. The field is parameters for which to run the report. I can add photos if that would help.

Comment: Bump. Any help on this? @blob1 is an attempt to edit an exisiting BLOB using the REPLACE function. Seen this on a similar Stack post but it has not worked sadly...

Comment: Two examples of blobs, one that works and one that doesn't would be useful.